# appearanceWhenContainedIn not working as expected with UITableView and UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I created a simple project with a UINavigationController, a UIBarButtonItem on the right, and a UITableView. For testing, I want to use appearanceWhenContainedIn: to color the UIBarButtonItems on the UINavigationController orange while also coloring UIButtons in the UITableView red. Alone, each styling works correctly. But when I use both together, it doesn't work. Why??

**Scenario 1 (Color UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationController):**

```
[[UIBarButtonItem 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

[image]

---

**Scenario 2 (Color UIButton in UITableView):**

```
[[UIButton 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

[image]

---

**Scenario 3 (Combine them):**

```
[[UIButton 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

[image]

---

Sample project can be downloaded via this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7nabaqc9oso907/AppBugTesting.zip

**Update:**
As I continue to diagnose the problem, I found that if I use "setBackgroundColor" of the UIButton to red rather than setTintColor, it shows the red background **and** the orange tint to the UIBarButtonItem. For some reason tinting both doesn't work... still not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
[[UIButton 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Of course this might turn some other things orange that you didn't intend.

Comment: Thanks this does work for what I want. But you're right, this would cause other objects to become orange which are not intended. I'm curious whether there is yet still a way around it. This answer seems the best as of yet.

Comment: You would have to deal with those other objects individually to keep them from becoming orange. - Alternatively, hey, you are making this bar button item manually, why don't you just set its tint color to orange at the time you do that?

Comment: So, in this demo I do. But with the current project I am working on, I am using similar code to change the style of the app from a single location in the delegate where I set all the colors. This is primarily because the plan is to re-skin the app for many purposes without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I figure. But what I'm saying is, this is buggy so the rock-bottom workaround solution is to set the tint color of individual bar button items by hand. Oh, and please file a bug with Apple! Your example is extremely compelling, since you can prove that it works with one or the other but not both appearance calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would create "empty" `UITableView` and `UINavigationController` subclasses to refer to, so as to avoid accidentally changing the appearance of other buttons.

```
[[UIButton 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyTableView class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar 
    appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil] 
        setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple's documentation:

> Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is not supported in iOS 7.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Comment: That was true during the beta period of iOS 7, but it is no longer the case. They got a lot of complaints about this and changed it. :)

Comment: Where is that documented?

Comment: It's documented by reality. :) `setTintColor:` does work on the appearance proxy, as the OP's examples clearly demonstrate. Previously, it didn't just not work, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: The change you claim was made isn't mentioned in the document I linked to. It's also not mentioned in in the UIAppearance Protocol Reference, and tintColor doesn't show up if you follow the instructions listed here for getting a list of methods and properties conforming to the protocol: https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521

Comment: The fact that it works in some cases doesn't mean it is supported behavior. It is by definition undocumented if it is not in any documentation or in the public headers.

Comment: Your app used to crash if you tried to use `setTintColor:` on the appearance proxy: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-setTintColor: is not allowed for use with the appearance proxy. Perhaps you want to use the barTintColor property.'` They took that away, showing that this is now allowed. I agree there is something odd about its status, and tint color is buggy in many ways (and Apple knows it). But it is wrong to tell the OP that he can't do what he's trying to do. It might be buggy but it is not illegal to try it.